# How to secure .Net Core application for trial with certificates

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, openssl, x509certificate, x509certificate2

The idea is to put a time bomb in the .Net Core application (it's beta/trial, not fully usable product, it's fine to do from legal point of view).

I wanted to use X509 certificate to accomplish that but having a hard time understanding how it works and what needs to be done.

So far, with OpenSSL, I created a private key (let's call it trial.key):

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out trial.key 2048
```

, then created a certificate with -days argument (trial.pem) and password "password":

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key trial.key -sha256 -days 4 -out trial.pem
```

and at then end trial.cert:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in trial.pem -out trial.crt
```

I add trial.crt to the application and check dates at startup:

```
private static void CheckTrialCert()
{
    var trialCert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine("Certificates", "trial.crt"), "password");

    if (trialCert.NotAfter < DateTime.Now)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    };
}
```

The problem is that user can find trial.crt on the disk and replace it with own created certificate without time restriction (assuming he knows the password) and use the application.

What can be done here? Is there a way I can hardcode private key within application and check if trial.crt has been signed with my private key?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to embed a certificate directly in code. However, this won't stop knowledgeable user from abusing your restriction. .NET applications can be easily decompiled, the logic can be traced and modified using tools such as ildasm.exe. In other words, what you are trying to accomplish is working against non-educated users.

To decompilation harder, you can use .NET obfuscation tools. However they have some side effects such as broken exception stacktrace. You need to find a balance between security, maintainability and implementation costs considering possible negative effects.

But still, gived all this, keep in mind that there is no 100% resistant solution, any application can be cracked, the question is about costs to break it.

Comment: Code will be obfuscated so I'm safe on this side.